# EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream"

Tags: javascript, servlets

*EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.*

Why I'm getting this error when sending a request from javascript to servlet?

Comment: Are you using webpack's hot loading?  If a route is being handled before the hot loader can use it, then this is how the hot loader complains.  Additionally, if you've loaded the hot loader to production, this error can occur as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the header of the message before sending it:

```
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });
```

You can follow this article for more information:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: The URL helped me. Thank you!